# Error: expected expression before ';' token char

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I am experimenting with a code, I have looked through the other posts, but couldn't figure it out, could you help me out on why I am getting:

```
error: expected expression before ';' token
    char passwd[] = PASSWORD;
```

=========================

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE 100
#define PASSWORD ********

int main()
{
    int count = 0;
    char buff[SIZE] = " ";
    char passwd[] = PASSWORD;
...
```

Comment: You probably meant: `#define PASSWORD "********"`

Comment: gg, no re, thank you for the quick fix

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`#define` directive would define a label for some primitive value.

This implies your code will be interpreted as `char passwd[]=********;` in compile time.

You probably need quotes around the **:

```
#define PASSWORD "********"
```

Answer (score 2):

`PASSWORD` has to be a string literal, in your code it's just multiple multiplication operators which is why the error message. To make it a string literal use double quotes like this

```
#define PASSWORD "********"
```

Answer (score 0):

The method in _Danny_ds_ and *iharob*'s answer is correct. Also, you can use the `strcpy` function to copy the `constant` into the `string` `passwd`. Like This: `strcpy (passwd, PASSWORD);`

You can read [this](http://www.programiz.com/c-programming/library-function/string.h/strcpy) tutorial on `strcpy`.

**NOTE:** You also have to make the changes mentioned in the above answers.